# Hibernate 3.x to 5.x migration issues

Tags: migration, hibernate-5.x, hibernate3

I am migrating hibernate 3.x to latest version 5.x and I see many issues that I need some help with.

1. SessionFactory.evict() - My code uses SessionFactory.evict() which I don't see in 5.x. What should I replace this code with? HibernateTemplate.evict()?
2. Changed **AnnotationSessionFactoryBean** to **LocalSessionFactoryBean** in spring config xml. AnnotationSessionFactoryBean had properties **configurationClass** and **namingStrategy**. What should these be replaced with?
3. Class **HibernateInterceptor** is used in spring config xml and now it is not found in spring 4.x under hibernate5 package.
4. ConnectionProvider.configure() is missing in Hibernate.

I am using,
Spring - 4.3.9.RELEASE
Hibernate - 5.2.10.Final

Answer (score 1):

you see this image, then find it on github.

[about version 5.2.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Z0L.png)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know of any solution for HibernateInterceptor?

Comment: Sorry,For a long time did not come back. Why not use mybatis?